# How to Random Images with delay in a secs in Xamarin Forms and Display into XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to random images and implement delays in a seconds in xamarin forms.

**This is my XAML Code**

```
<Image x:Name="RandomImageList" Source="Album1.jpg">
```

**This is my C# Code**

```
List<string> imageList = new List<string> { "Album1.jpg", "Album2.jpg", "Album3.jpg" };

        var random = new Random();
        var next = random.Next(4);
        var image = imageList[next];

        RandomImageList.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(image);
```

**And this is the result during i run this code.**

*System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
*

Comment: Using a debugger, step through the code. Which line of code causes that exception?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i think here var image = imageList[next];

Comment: Do `var next = random.Next(imageList.Count);` Your list has only 3 items. You need indices from [0, 2], which you get by passing `3` to Next. BUT don't "hardcode" numbers like that. Make it clear where the number comes from; in this case, its the list length.

Comment: Sorry, that comment of mine was misleading -- I've deleted it -- I think you got that message because its inside a view component, which complained. Nothing you need to do about Reflection. Rather, you need to discover exactly which line complained, and then figure out what is wrong with it. In this case, probably a bad index value...

Comment: i'll try your code give me var next = random.Next(imageList.Count); and same error i dont know were i put that indexes like [0,2]?

Comment: You don't put "indexes like [0,2]" anywhere. I was just explaining why that line of code is needed. **Have you stepped through the code using a debugger, to verify which line causes the exception?** That is the most important thing to do. Because this code might not be the problem at all. Set a breakpoint on the first line. When VS stops there, hit F10 (or the "Step Over" icon in  the Debug Toolbar. Do this several times, with View / Output pane visible, so you can see any new messages there. If you make it all the way through this code, then it isn't the problem at all.

Comment: Also, in VS menu. choose Debug / Windows / Exception Settings. If "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is not checked, then click on it, to turn that checkmark on. This should do a better job of stopping in the debugger as soon as a problem happens. Showing you where the problem really is.

Comment: The exact problem is that you are using `ImageSource.FromResource` which is used to show [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#embedded-images) , change it to `FromFile` should be able to solve the problem , follow the Divyesh_08's solution below .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, just do this.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<string> imageList = new List<string> { "add.png", "compare.png", "down.png", "remove.png" };

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var next = random.Next(4);
            var image = imageList[next];
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            RandomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(image);
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thankyou for your answer. Now the problem is i want to save the new random image and display it when i restart the app.

Comment: It's simple save the selected image's index value in local db or some other way and when next time you open app get the index from stored place and display image accordingly using that index from list of images.